# How to hide Soft Keyboard, open in Android Home Screen/Launcher, from Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an application which blocks any input from Home Screen widgets on certain conditions.

I have a foreground service which is running always. I can hide soft keyboard if it is within my application. But I don't know how to hide it from Home Screen/Launcher.

The InputMethodManager doesn't hide the keyboard if it is open in the Home Screen or in any other application.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` add it within your activity tag of manifest and try

Comment: I want to hide keyboard from Android Home Screen not from my application.

Comment: here Home Screen is activity or something else?

Comment: That is Android's launcher screen..